# Randomly rename a file method

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to randomly rename a file:

```
       File.Move
            (@"C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\file.txt", @"C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\file"
               + Helpers_Generic.GenerateRandomInt(10, 1000, driver).ToString() + ".txt");
```

It's working well but I would like to put it in a method for ease of use:

```
public static void RenameFile(string SourceFileName, string destFileName)
    {
        string randFileExten = GenerateRandomInt(100, 10000).ToString();
        File.Move(SourceFileName, destFileName + randFileExten);
    }
```

That does not work well because the random string appears at the end of the file name. What needs to be done here ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the arguments you are supplying to RenameFile.
Is it ` RenameFile(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\file.txt", @"C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\file"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question, you asked for this:

```
public static void RenameFile(string SourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
    var randFileExten = GenerateRandomInt(100, 10000);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(destFileName);
    string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(destFileName);
    string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(destFileName);

    File.Move(SourceFileName, Path.Combine(folder, $"{file}{randFileExten}{ext}"));
}
```

But since it's very likely you want the destination file name to match the source file name (other than the uniquifier), I think we can do even better:

```
public static void RenameFile(string SourceFileName, string destFolderPath)
{
    var randFileExten = GenerateRandomInt(100, 10000);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(sourceFileName);
    string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFileName);

    File.Move(SourceFileName, Path.Combine(destFolderPath, $"{file}{randFileExten}{ext}"));
}
```

Notice the 2nd parameter is named differently, and the method is different to match.

We can also easily provide an overload for the case where the destination folder is the same:

```
public static void RenameFile(string SourceFileName)
{
    string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(SourceFileName);
    RenameFile(SourceFileName, folder);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your answer Joel.